# Alternating Path's influence on Popularity in Graph Matching Problem

Tags: graph-theory

Assume we have a Matching M in a Bipartite Graph and  an Alternating Path P with respect to M , that has a (1,1) Edge in it (both the end points of this edge prefer to be matched together other than their partners in M) will M $\oplus$ P = M' always result a More Popular Matching than M ? ( not the most popular , just a little bit more popular than what it was )

ps : We know that if a Matching is Popular then it doesn't have such a path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're referring to the same notion of a "popular matching" as in your previous question, the one defined in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7e5e/ac6c1aa3c13baeddf4c92ebbfca57aab0b8a.pdf): the graph is bipartite, all vertices rank their neighbors by preference, and a popular matching $M$ is one such that there is no matching $M'$ such that more vertices prefer $M'$ to $M$ than $M$ to $M'$.

The answer to your question is **no**: the resulting matching is not "more popular". We are guaranteed that the endpoints of the $(1,1)$ edge are happier in $M \oplus P$ than in $M$. Also, each endpoint of $P$ that is unsaturated in $M$ becomes saturated in $M \oplus P$, so it is better off. (Usually, we consider augmenting paths, such that both endpoints of $P$ are unsaturated in $M$, so this gives us four vertices that are happier with $M \oplus P$ than with $M$.) But if $P$ is long enough, there could be plenty of other vertices in $P$ that were happier in $M$ than in $M \oplus P$.

Two warnings about this:

1. In Theorem 1 of the linked paper, we look for alternating paths in $G_M$: the graph in which all edges that are $(-1,-1)$ with respect to $M$ - that is, all edges that would make both endpoints worse off - are deleted. If $P$ is an alternating path in $G_M$, not just in $G$, and $|M \oplus P| \ge |M|$ (so that at least one endpoint of $P$ becomes happier) then the condition you want does hold, since for every new edge, at least one endpoint is happier with it than in its previous edge.
2. Calling a matching "more popular" than another is slightly misleading because it suggests that you're certain to have a sequence of more popular matchings until you get to a popular one. In fact, it's possible to have a sequence of matchings $M_1, M_2, \dots, M_k$ such that more vertices prefer $M_{i+1}$ to $M_i$ than the reverse ($M_{i+1}$ is more popular than $M_i$) and yet more vertices prefer $M_1$ to $M_k$ than the reverse ($M_1$ is more popular than $M_k$).

Comment: Thanks for your respone , yes its the same paper , I repeatedly forget the fact that these are happening in GM ,  my problem was that I kept seeing that switching edges with the alternating path makes the matching more popular all over the paper and it wasnt easy to figure out why till you reminded me of the GM . you made good points here and there Thank you so much .